# Защита от декомпиляции exe файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Как можно сделать трудно обходимую защиту от декомпиляции exe файла скомпилированным c помощью PyInstaller'ом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Про пайинсталлер.

1. питон не компилируется в машинный код, а в виртуальном коде есть все имена переменных и названия функций. Его всегда можно вернуть к исходному.
2. pyinstaller компилирует py в pyc, а потом пакует в zip.
3. на данный момент не существует декомпилятора последней версии питона. пока нет.

### Как максимально защитить

Есть такой компилятор как cython - он транслирует py -> cи -> машинный код. Оформи свой код как библиотеку cython + файл запуска py. Скомпилируй проект в pyd (библиотека с машинным кодом). А потом скорми pyinstaller.

Тогда при распаковке pyinstaller программы увидят зависимости и pyd файлы твоего модуля. Получить из них код будет довольно сложно - проще написать с нуля.

Не буду подробно писать ещё одну статью. Их в интернете уже много и без меня. https://habr.com/ru/post/138537/