# Как защитить своё ПО от пиратства

Tags: python, безопасность, юридические-аспекты

Есть вопрос, каким образом можно защитить своё приложение от пиратства?
Я собираюсь разработать свой программный продукт. Допустим CRM. У него есть версия, для установки на локальный сервер. Естественно есть лицензионное соглашение о том, что компания имеет право на пользование в течении определённого времени. Каким образом можно сделать данное приложение недоступным к использованию спустя какое-то время? или сделать так, что бы это ПО не распространилось далее в интернете? Какие методы привязки к IP или к серверу могут быть?
Хотелось бы использовать Python для написания ПО.

Comment: Никак. . . . . .

Comment: винду пиратят, фотошоп пиратят, вы думаете, что сможете совершить то, что не могут майкрософт и адобе?

Comment: майкрософт и адобе  стоят милиарды. но как относится к пиратсву майкрософт - им насрать, они даже не защищаются .

Answer (score 2):

Нужно написать лицензионный сервис. Который будет аутентифицировать клиентов использующих вашу CRM.(А привязывать клиентов можно к hwid) Но следует понимать, что софт написанный на python достаточно просто пиратится.

Для защиты исходников стоит использовать pyarmor + сборку в бинарь на наиболее свежей версии python(его сложнее разобрать и нет готовых решений). Но это не панацея. Любой софт в теории может быть угнан и разобран на куски.

Один из вариантов - размазывать закладки проверяющие лицензию по всему объему кода, делать их неявными приправляя обфускацией. + Динамическая загрузка удалённых модулей из ваших дополнительных сервисов. Т.е Код как бы загружается с удалённого ресурса и подгружается в рантайме.

В этих модулях стоит так же разместить скрытые закладки проверки лицензии, не обязательно связанного с главным сервисом аутентификации.

**Полностью защитить никода не выйдет**. Необходимо создать условие таких затрат на взлом, потраченные ресурсы которых будут фактически больше чем расходы на защиту от взлома.

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал асимметричную криптографию для этого. При активации приложения генерируется подпись данных (время окончания подписки, железо, прочее). Внутри программы зашит общий ключ, по которому эти данные расшифровываются и делаются проверки.

Второй этап - скомпилить код через cython.

Comment: Будет сильно надо - и скомпилированный код тоже пропатчат

Comment: если эта штука работает у 100 клиентов и цена у неё меньше 50000, то патчить её никто не будет

Comment: Потом от 101-го она утечёт в интернет и её расковыряет какой-нибудь энтузиаст чисто по приколу)

Comment: он же скажет что софт гавно и так же останемся при ста клиентах на абонентке

Answer (score 0):

В тегах увидел python, вы можете преобразовать python код в exe файл, обычно такие методы называют «native obfuscator» которые преобразуют код в «нативный язык» на котором написан python. После получения exe файла на него можно наложить протект от дебага и прочих «reverse engineering» утилит. Популярными являются: Themida, Enigma, VMP (является лучшим из всех). Конечно, это лишь малая часть.

Также для python можно использовать pyminifer, но смысла от него будет очень мало.
Мои советы:

1. не писать приложения с защитой на python, т.к. он создан для лёгких целей
2. не используйте pyinstaller, подробнее расписано в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493272/)